# Error-> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, rasa

```
I am using anaconda prompt. I want to run rasa. I have installed successfully keras in system as well as in virtual environments too, using command **conda install keras** .
But when I run the command **rasa init** then in NLU traing It gives me an error for ModuleNotFound: keras. What should I do resolve this error and successfully run the rasa chatbot?

I have checked that keras2.4.3 is installed in both my system and virtual environment using command **conda list**.
Error I am getting when running **rasa init** command:
Welcome to Rasa! 

To get started quickly, an initial project will be created.
If you need some help, check out the documentation at https://rasa.com/docs/rasa.
Now let's start! 

? Please enter a path where the project will be created [default: current directory] .
? Directory 'C:\Users\om sai infotech\OneDrive\Desktop\organization_BOT(complete_dynamic)\organization_BOT\bot' is not empty. Continue? Yes
Created project directory at 'C:\Users\om sai infotech\OneDrive\Desktop\organization_BOT(complete_dynamic)\organization_BOT\bot'.
Finished creating project structure.
? Do you want to train an initial model?  Yes
Training an initial model...
The configuration for pipeline and policies was chosen automatically. It was written into the config file at '.\config.yml'.
2021-11-10 18:58:11 INFO rasa.model - Data (domain) for Core model section changed.
2021-11-10 18:58:11 INFO rasa.model - Data (messages) for NLU model section changed.
2021-11-10 18:58:11 INFO rasa.model  strong text- Data (nlg) for NLG responses section changed.
Training NLU model...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python39\Scripts\rasa.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rasa\__main__.py", line 118, in main
    cmdline_arguments.func(cmdline_arguments)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rasa\cli\scaffold.py", line 235, in run
    init_project(args, path)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rasa\cli\scaffold.py", line 130, in init_project
    print_train_or_instructions(args, path)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rasa\cli\scaffold.py", line 69, in print_train_or_instructions
    training_result = rasa.train(domain, config, training_files, output)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rasa\api.py", line 109, in train
    return rasa.utils.common.run_in_loop(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rasa\utils\common.py", line 296, in run_in_loop
    result = loop.run_until_complete(f)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rasa\model_training.py", line 108, in train_async
    return await _train_async_internal(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rasa\model_training.py", line 288, in _train_async_internal
    await _do_training(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rasa\model_training.py", line 334, in _do_training
    model_path = await _train_nlu_with_validated_data(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rasa\model_training.py", line 758, in _train_nlu_with_validated_data
    await rasa.nlu.train.train(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rasa\nlu\train.py", line 96, in train
    trainer = Trainer(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rasa\nlu\model.py", line 164, in __init__
    components.validate_requirements(cfg.component_names)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rasa\nlu\components.py", line 58, in validate_requirements
    from rasa.nlu import registry
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rasa\nlu\registry.py", line 12, in <module>
    from rasa.nlu.classifiers.diet_classifier import DIETClassifier
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rasa\nlu\classifiers\diet_classifier.py", line 24, in <module>
    from rasa.utils.tensorflow.models import RasaModel, TransformerRasaModel
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rasa\utils\tensorflow\models.py", line 47, in <module>
    from rasa.utils.tensorflow.temp_keras_modules import TmpKerasModel
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rasa\utils\tensorflow\temp_keras_modules.py", line 16, in <module>
    from keras.callbacks import Callback, History
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

I am using anaconda prompt. I want to run rasa. I have installed successfully keras in system as well as in virtual environments too, using command **conda install keras** .
But when I run the command **rasa init** then in NLU traing It gives me an error for ModuleNotFound: keras. What should I do resolve this error and successfully run the rasa chatbot?

```
I have checked that keras2.4.3 is installed in both my system and virtual environment using command **conda list**.
```

Please help me in resolving this issue, I shall be highly thankful to you.

Comment: Anaconda installs a new python interpreter, you are using a different python interpreter (installed in C:\Python39), each interpreter is completely independent and does not see packages installed in the other interpreter, you should use the python interpreter installed by anaconda.

Comment: How can I use it?